# Get first image of custom post type wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have this code

```
function display_categoria($args) {
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'job_listing',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 5
));


while ($query->have_posts()) {
  echo $query->the_post();
   $id=get_the_id();
   echo $query1=get_permalink();
  }

 wp_reset_query();
}

add_shortcode( 'este', 'display_categoria' );
```

in theory i can solve it placing in the loop

```
 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail();
                            }
```

but many entries not have a thumbnail (featured images), Can understand?

Comment: So some do have thumbnail? For those that don't have it, did you check they actually have the featured image set in their posts?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to featured images @TurtleTread

Answer (score 1):

This should retrieve the url of the first image for each post. Insert it after the "$id=get_the_id();" line

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $id 
); 
$images = get_posts( $args );
if ( $images ) {
    $first_image_id = $images[0];

    //do something with the image

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```